# Div margin pushing it inside

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to understand a bit of CSS

http://jsfiddle.net/f2mZz/

What I want to understand is why giving `article`  `margin-left: 15px;` (or anywhere) will push its margin inside the div and not outside? What property does this and why?

Note that in the CSS that property is not given.

Comment: Refer to the specifications http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html .Get familiar with box model and how margins behave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the relevant HTML:

```
<section id="main_section">
    <article>
        <header>
            <h1>titlu articol 1</h1>
            <p>subtitlu</p>
        </header>
        <p>continut articol</p>
        <footer>
            <p>articol scris de bunica</p>
        </footer>
    </article>
    <article>
        <header>
            <h1>titlu articol 2</h1>
            <p>subtitlu</p>
        </header>
        <p>continut articol 2</p>
        <footer>
            <p>articol scris de bunica</p>
        </footer>
    </article>
</section>
```

and you have the following CSS:

```css
#main_section {
    border: 1px dashed green;
    float: left;
    width:660px;
    margin: 30px;
    /*720->280*/
}
article {
    background: #FFFBCC;
    border: 1px dotted red;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

The `#main_section` elmement is floated left, which means that it establishes a block formatting context.  That means that any margins of the child elements, in this case, the `article` elements, are aligned with respect to the bounding box of the parent element (`#main_section`).

If the `#main_section` were not floated, then the margins would collapse in the usual fashion.

Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting

**Note:** This example is slightly more complex because of the border on `#main_section`.
The presence of the border will prevent the vertical margins on the `article` children elements from collapsing with the margins on the parent block.  To see the effect, change the 
`border` to `outline` and take out the `float`, which mmakes the effects of the block formatting context easier to discern.

Comment: What means "respect bounding box"?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly...

The margin is the area outside of the box and the padding is the area inside. In this case, the margin-bottom is associated with the article, the part with a yellow background and a red border, which is inside the main content box. The bottom margin pushes the article up from the bottom of the main content area. What is pushing the text inside the article box up is the padding, which is set to 20 px, AND the footer, which is justified to the right.

The article text is pushed right by the padding.

Also the article boxes are inside the main_section box, which has a green border, and that is what is pushed left, but it's margin setting.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with **box-sizing** if I understand your question correctly.

```
box-sizing:content-box;
```

*Default. The width and height properties (and min/max properties) includes only the content. Border, padding, or margin are not included*

```
box-sizing:border-box;
```

*The width and height properties (and min/max properties) includes content, padding and border, but not the margin*

Also notice the **-webkit- -moz-** prefixes in the example

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/joopmicroop/4H34m/)

```
#first{
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    background: red;
}
#second{
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: yellow;
}
div{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border: 20px solid black;
    margin:20px;
    padding:20px;
}
```